# Determine the roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let $P_n$ be a degree $n$ polynomial such that for all $a\in \mathbb R$,
$$P_n(2cos(a))=2cos(na)$$
I want to determine the roots of $P_n$. Being of degree $n$, $P_n$ cannot have more than $n$ roots. But i found $2n$ roots!! Here is how I found them.

The equation  $cos(na)=0$ implies that $na=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z$.
Hence for each $k$ in $\mathbb Z$, the real $b_k=2cos(\dfrac{\pi}{2n}+\dfrac{k\pi}{n})$ is a root of $P_n$. Now we determine the values of $k$ that produce repetition in the value of $b_k$. So let $b_k=b_l$, this gives that $$\dfrac{\pi}{2n}+\dfrac{k\pi}{n}=\dfrac{\pi}{2n}+\dfrac{l\pi}{n}+2m\pi$$
or 
 $$\dfrac{\pi}{2n}+\dfrac{k\pi}{n}=-\dfrac{\pi}{2n}-\dfrac{k\pi}{n}+2m'\pi$$
$m$ and $m'$ being any integers.
Hence $$k=l+2m$$ or 
$$k+l+1=2m'$$
These give that the distinct roots are $$b_k=2cos(\dfrac{\pi}{2n}+\dfrac{k\pi}{n})$$
with $k=0..2n$.

Did I do something wrong? thank you for your help!!

Comment: When you say $b_k=b_l$, this does not imply that they are the cosine of the same angle (modulo $2\pi$). You may have opposite angles...

Comment: That's what I wrote, they are equal or opposite (modulo $2\pi$).

Comment: You're right, sorry I read too fast.

Comment: However, I believe you didn't take it into account in your last formula: $2\cos(\frac\pi{2n}+\frac{k\pi}n)=2\cos(\frac\pi{2n}+\frac{l\pi}n)$ for $l=2n-1-k$, so you counted every solution twice (and the first one three times, if you consider $k=0, k=2n-1, k=2n$)

Comment: Exactly, thank you !!!